# how to implement OAuth2 and PHP Rest Api for android application

Tags: php, android, rest, oauth

i found many resource from google, but at the end i am not able to decide in what manner i can create and use PHP REST API that uses OAuth2 for authentication where the request is only initiated and consume by Android application..

as i am really new to OAuth and Android, i am not getting how to create an Android app that uses OAuth2 authentication for authorization with PHP Rest API..

i just want to know from where to start and what may be the possible first step for doing that.

i don't want the full code , but at least the steps involved to get the things working... please help..

i have enough confidence that i can create Android app and PHP Rest api and will try my best to follow and learn the steps required...

i know developing android app and all about php too.. but new to OAuth 2.0

Answer (score 1):

I was going through the same problem before and make this a library I  to handel OAuth2 in Android 
https://github.com/AliAbozaid/OAuth2Library

Comment: thanks for your important time.. but i am learning and understanding it using this link: http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/ and upto now.. i am getting it is easy to setup and depends on.. me and my requirements...

Comment: My library is to handle(token, refresh and save) credentials in Android not from server side you

Comment: thanks a lot sir, but i need full set up for server and client and i know i need to study and implement that.. and so far i have successfully created my server in codeigniter and now learning more about server setup and usage.. and after implementing i will for sure going to post here my solution.. for others... :)

Comment: so, have you implementing your solution?